# Reader role assignment to registered application via powershell at subscription scope

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-subscription

Trying to assign **Reader** role for **application** at **subscription** level using the following powershell command. but it gets failed

```
foreach ($Id in Get-AzSubscription)
{
    New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId '<Application-Object-Id>' -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope '/subscriptions/$Id'
}
```

getting this error "New-AzRoleAssignment: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'"

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing your code to:

```
foreach ($subscription in Get-AzSubscription)
{
    New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId '<Application-Object-Id>' -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope '/subscriptions/$subscription.Id'
}
```

Essentially the issue with your code was that `$Id` variable is an object of type `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureSubscription` which contains information about the subscription and not just the subscription id.

Comment: After this change too getting the same error. *** Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' ***

Comment: Please try to run `New-AzRoleAssignment` with `-Debug` switch parameter i.e. `New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId '<Application-Object-Id>' -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope '/subscriptions/$subscription.Id' -Debug` and it should show you the exact error message. I get the same error if I use an invalid application object id. HTH.